# Remote repository package went missing after package removed from pypi.org

Tags: backup

I recently lost a package in my artifactory remote repository because of the package itself disappeared from pypu.org as I didn't know that artifactory remote cache works as a proxy cache only. So I need some detailed setups on how to avoid this happening again in the future.

I looked into the official docs and a lot of stuff related to backups in the UI never found it in my account administration.

Answer (score 0):

Because JFrog Artifactory has `Cleanup Unused Cached Artifacts` in the Maintenance part and based on `cron expression`, it deletes packages.